# What is Inceptions End

Tags: inception

I have seen Inception many times. Every time I come with a new conclusion. What I feel is that he is in dream right from the beginning, when he comes to meet syto. But, this is also confusing that he see's his children's face at the end but still at the end Totem is still spinning. Any one with the answer.?

Comment: It's a bullshit ending meant to "make you wonder" about the movie's reality. There is no clear indication either way, so an answer is not possible.

Comment: @amarillo : I agreee with you. Movie starts in a dream.

Comment: The totem is still spinning, but the ambiguity is over whether it's going to topple (real) or not (dream). The filmmaker left this **deliberately** ambiguous.

Comment: @amarillo - No, the kids are wearing [different clothes](http://clothesonfilm.com/inception-jeffrey-kurland-costume-qa/14317/) and they're [older](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_buVAhLdEfbg/TQbZANl9I6I/AAAAAAAAAig/KxT_78aV2q4/s1600/Kids%2BComparison%2B1.jpg).

Comment: @Richard Yeah they purposely kept it vague.

Comment: Michael Caine did an interview where he said what he believed the ending was meant to be.